# How to find the java update version?

Tags: java

I have a jre installed installed in my windows.

When I use the command 
    java -version

I get the output -

```
java version "1.7.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0-b147)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 21.0-b17, mixed mode)
```

I can see only the major version 1.7. 
How to know which version of JRE update it is ?

Comment: You mean whether it's the `b17` or the `b147`?

Comment: Its already showing  `Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0-b147)` What else you need?

Comment: There is no 147 in [jre 1.7 update versions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase7-521261.html) . And I thought b147 is the build number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at this page from the release note: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jdk7-naming-418744.html

It seems you have the 1st java 7 version.

> Oracle periodically makes updates available and, when an update occurs, the version string will also include the update version number. So, JDK 7 update 4, or JDK 7u4, will have the version string "1.7.0_4".

Answer (score 9):

Calling `java -version` will give you the installed version, including the update number (here: 51):

```
java version "1.7.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)
```

It seems like you have the *base version* installed, so there is no update number:

```
java version "1.7.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0-b147)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 21.0-b17, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 3):

I guess the build gives you the update you have.

You can try this as well-

java -fullversion

Version number translation:   1.6.0_34   is, in English,   Java 6 Update 34

Comment: That gives me --
java full version "1.7.0-b147"

Comment: I think this means that you have the release version of Java 7

Comment: Just a simple "Google" of your version string will give you the answer - https://www.404techsupport.com/2011/07/java-7-0-download/

Answer (score 0):

Normally the `jre folder` is named something like `1.VersionNumber.0_UpdateNumber`

For 64 bit you can find this folder under `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java`

If your version Number just look like this: `1.VersionNumber.0`, this means that you have the first release of given Java Version.

Comment: The problem is somebody renamed the folder to jre.